# JQuery JavaScript Regex expression to currency

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to format number to currency using JavaScript, but every regex expression that I try doesn't work.

I have a paragraph:

```
<p class="text-primary" id="totalPaymentAllocatedLabel">Allocated Amount: $1,050.52</p>
```

Then I enter in a "number" input the value: 1150

Using JQuery, I try to edit the paragraph:

```
$("#totalPaymentAllocatedLabel").val(newValue.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, ""));
```

Then, it displays Allocated Amount: $1150.00 I would like `$1,150.00`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm new and dumb with regex. Should I replace with value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as dollars currency string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript)

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49261076/applying-currency-format-using-replace-and-a-regular-expression/49266204#49266204

Comment: Nope. There is no answer in the topic tat you sent

Comment: I thought you were trying to do something like obtaining `$1,150.00` from `1150`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript